# How and where are variables that are used throughout the ASP.net Project created/stored?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to be able to store variables that are accessible to all of the other files in my ASP.net project but can be modified programatically.  What I am looking for is something akin to being able to pull information from the web.config file for say the database connection strings (ex System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cnDatabase"].ToString())

I have variables that have values that are shared amongst all of the other pages and I would like to be able to modify in one location instead of having to update the same value in 4+ aspx.cs pages.

Comment: I'm guessing you mean "modified programatically" (though I can't spell it), not "modified problematically"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AppSettings in the Web.Config file

or

public/internal constants

Answer (score 1):

If you want something that is global to the application where you can add custom variables, use a Global.asax.  Anything you add here will be available through the Global variable inherited in all pages and controls.  If all you need is a key/value store, you can use the Application or Session static variables that are inherited in all pages and controls.  Application (which is just a static instance of HttpApplicationState) is an object that you can use as a Hashtable to store custom values that will be available on all pages for all users.  And, Session (HttpSessionState) is available the same way for use as a Hashtable, but the values you store will be unique per user session.

Note: if you need to access any of these objects outside of a page or control (ie. a custom class used within the context of a page request), you can get a reference to them through the current http context (HttpContext.Current).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the Settings feature of a project.

Here's a good introduction:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(VS.80).aspx

Note:  this isn't available for "Web Site" type projects, just ASP.Net Web Application projects.